# Переменные в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, django, шаблоны

Хотелось бы использовать тег {% url %} дабы не хардкодить,в связи с чем столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

1. Передаю модель,содержащую данные о страницах

   {% for page in pagelist %}
2. Хочу на место параметра вставить имя страницы,но Django ругается на подобную запись

   {% url 'blog.views.view' pagename={{page.name}} %}

   {% endfor %}

Подскажите,пожалуйста,что я делаю не так

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то в конструкциях {% %} переменные нужно использовать без {{ }}. Попробуйте pagename=page.name

Comment: Вы оказались правы,спасибо большое.

Comment: @fobedep вынесите в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Как ответил @fobedep, в конструкциях `{% %}` переменные нужно использовать без `{{ }}`.

Comment: @fobedep, добавь ответ, я свой удалю.